# How to limit APT packages

Tags: apt, package-management, live-usb

So I'm sitting here in internet cafes, programming on the move, and I need to update my system. Great. I'll just run `apt-get upd`- ah the mother, I have 600 packages to download and install, and 100 packages to upgrade? Yeah, bunk that noise, right? I don't have time or internet speed to wait for that.

My question is simply - is there a way to install, say, 50% of `apt` inventories, or do I have to just try and `ctl+z` it and hope that I didn't stop on a crucial part of the installation process that makes my system unusable (it's happened), and forces the need of `dpkg --configure -a` before doing literally anything else with my system?

Comment: I wouldn't trust an Internet Cafe with coffee let alone software downloads and installing whatever came off their wifi.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - while I'm normally paranoid too, deb packages are GPG signed.  If you are installing with only trusted keys you will be safe no matter the mirror.  Someone could intercept your traffic, but if they don't give you a cryptographically validated payload, apt will not install it.  `apt-key list`  to see all the keys you have trusted.

Comment: @dpb never saw "normal" and "paranoid" paired together :) I just don't like Internet Cafes in general I guess. Anyway it was just a comment and not an answer. To each his own.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix haha. :)  Agreed on not liking untrusted networks.  VPN/HTTPS FTW.

Comment: Well when you live in a third world country and don't have your own computer, things get a little complicated until one of the two things change. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you are downloading from an internet cafe, your best bet would be to download the packages using `apt-get` first, and then install them.

Before you start, you may like to get the list of packages to upgrade into a text file (*optional*):

```
sudo apt list --upgradable > upgrade.txt
```

And view it with your favorite text editor.

If you run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -d # or dist-upgrade if you want
```

You can interrupt this command at any time without any problems using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Once the command completes fully (without <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), then do the proper upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade # or dist-upgrade if that is what you did
```

Comment: @karel "easier to install offline"? How?

Comment: It makes it easier to see what you're doing when the list of upgradeable packages is saved to a text file using the command: `sudo apt list --upgradable`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The -d flag is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing a system upgrade, not just an update.

I would look into `apt-offline`. Essentially, you'd be preparing a package list that you then download. After it is downloaded, you can install the upgrade without internet connection.

See here for detailed instructions: https://www.ostechnix.com/fully-update-upgrade-offline-debian-based-systems/

The benefit of this method is that you get a distinct stop after the download, and the download can be done in stages. Also, the install is done without need for an internet connection.

The Downside is you need enough disk space to hold the entire upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like synaptic to select which packages to upgrade manually.

Comment: I suggest expanding this with information about how to do that.